# Match three errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;        
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileBackground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] cookies;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        void Initialize(){
            int cookieToUse = Random.Range(0, cookies.Length);
            GameObject cookie = Instantiate(cookies[cookieToUse], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            cookie.transform.parent = this.transform;
            cookie.name = this.gameObject.name; 
        }
    }
}
```

this is the two errors that are coming up in VS

> Initialize(); error code is  The name 'Initialize' does not exist in
> the context  (CS0103)

> 'Random' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and
> 'System.Random' (CS0104) any suggestions

Comment: You are defining the method Initialize() inside the the method Update and trying to use it outside the scope where you defined it. For the 2nd error it is self explanatory .. Unity found to definitions of Random class. You must specify which one you want to use

Comment: do you have Skype or whats app or Facebook because I'm following a YouTube video and the guy isn't getting errors

Comment: Post you questions here and i will answer. Did you tried to change what i told you?

Comment: im not following someone tried to edited it but Im new to this site never used it before

Comment: Well, the problem with you code is the following: You are defining the method Initialize() inside the method Update(). That way, you cannot use Initialize outside the methodUpdate(). So, when you try to use it inside the method Start() Unity cannot find it.

Comment: As for the Random, Unity is finding two Classes Random, one is inside the namespace UnityEngine, and the other is inside the namespace System. You have to specifies which one to use, for example change it to System.Random.Range(0, cookies.Length);

Comment: its not the second one Its the first one. the     void Initialize() is not throwing the error its the other one above that one and the random below     void Initialize()

Comment: I will post an answer correcting your code for you to close the topic. If you want more help, update your profile and add an email address and i will send you an email

Comment: I though my email was on here but its leoellis2015@yahoo.com I will also look to update it as well

Comment: I don't know how to update my email on here im new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

The first error happens because you are defining the method `Initialize()` inside the method `Update()`. Doing that way, you cannot use `Initialize()` outside of the method `Update()`.

The second error happens because Unity is founding two Random classes. One is in the namespace `System` and the other is in `UnityEngine`. You must tell Unity which one to use.

Below is the code snipped with the corrections.

```
using System;        
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TileBackground : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] cookies;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }


    void Initialize(){
        int cookieToUse = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, cookies.Length);
        GameObject cookie = Instantiate(cookies[cookieToUse], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        cookie.transform.parent = this.transform;
        cookie.name = this.gameObject.name; 
    }

}
```

Comment: the error for range popped up after I changed it as well

Comment: it fixed the two but now I have another error with Range 'Random' does not contain a definition for 'Range'(CS0107)

Comment: Range 'Random' does not contain a definition for 'Range'(CS0107)

Comment: My bad, change the System.Random.Range to UnityEngine.Random.Range . Already edited on the answer

Comment: see I had this before the and I coudnt see my objects in unity I don't know what is going on here

Comment: Hmm i didn't understood what you meant ... What objects can you see ?